# (openGL) Should handles to non existing uniforms be avoided?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my current project, I use multiple different shaders, which all have many of the same uniforms, primarily storing global information regarding lighting or render settings; as an example, all my fragment shaders contain the line:

```
//...
uniform float global_time;
//... and more variables
```

For this reason, I use a class to get and store the handles for these uniforms and automatically upload them each time an object with these shaders are called, meaning that I for each program have an object which at startup does:

```
//...
time_ID = glGetUniformLocation(this_ProgramID,"global_time");
//...
```

And for each iteration of the object every frame does:

```
//...
glUniform1f(time_ID,CPU_time);
//...
```

But for a single one of these shaders, there is one of these variables (in this case global_time) which I don't need.
As far as my experimenting shows, there are no negative consequences to just deleting global_time from its fragment shader, and the time send to the now non-existing uniform does not seem to cause any problems (neither undefined behavior, crashes or any notable drop in performance)... but is this really the case? are there no problems with sending data to a handle of a non-existing uniform?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  How can you get the `"handle of a non-existing uniform"`?  In the example shown `time_ID` will be `-1` if no uniform named `global_time` is found and the subsequent call to `glUniform1f` will generate a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: @G.M. No, In the specification is clearly specified: *"An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if [...] no variable with a location of location exists in the program object currently in use **and location is not -1** [...]"*

Comment: @Rabbid76 Indeed.  I should have read it more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a uniform doesn't "exist", then the return value of [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml) is -1.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 7.6 Uniform Variables](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=163&zoom=100,0,806), page 142:

> If the value of location is -1, the `Uniform*` commands will silently ignore the
>   data passed in, and the current uniform values will not be changed.

So it is no problem and well defined to set a uniform variable to the location -1.

---

If you've a set of data which is used in most of you shader programs, then I recommend to use a [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) or [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) and update a subset of the buffer once, when the data have changed respectively (in case of a time) at the begin of every frame.